# Access Cascading Combobox dependent on multiple others

Tags: ms-access, combobox, dependencies, cascadingdropdown, ms-access-forms

Is it possible to have a cascading combobox dependent on multiple factors?
For instance, Item2 is based on Item1Type and Item1Size. 
I've got Item2 dependent on Item1Type right now, but I'd like for it to be more refined.

Comment: Just expand the WHERE clause.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I was unsure and didn't want to royally screw anything up. Thank you! I'll go ahead and try it out.